# adding subtitles to a video in phonon pyqt4

Tags: video, pyqt4, subtitle, phonon

I'm building a media player pyqt4 using phonon. I've already built a basic player and now I'm trying to add subtitles to it, but I'm facing difficulties.
I have tried qlabel and qpainter with no success.
Any help will be highly appreciated..